# CSRF token mismatch when rendering a json in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, token, csrf, mismatch

I'm using lusca for handling csrf attacks on my application. in my express app when I render an html page and pass the _csrf token to it for placing on a hidden input everything is correct because lusca check the html _csrf token and find the match.

my controller:

```
response.render("root/home", {
    _csrf: response.locals._csrf
});
```

my html page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf}}" />
```

But when I want to export a json response for a **POST Request** I can't send my _csrf token so lusca can't find the match (I think problem is here) and give me this error:

Error: CSRF token mismatch

my controller:

```
response.json({
    status: "success"
});
```

**UPDATE:**

The **csrf secret** (not token, mind you) is being **regenerated or removed** some time between the initial **GET** and the **POST**. The only way this is possible is if the value stored as _csrfSecret in the session is changed or deleted between requests. Make sure your session is working properly.
[FROM THIS SOURCE](http://www.acnenomor.com/5366089p1/krakenjs-csrf-handling)

but still I can't find a solution!

**UPDATE 2:**

We have 2 strategies for generating csrf tokens... **per session** and **per request**. in my application tokens generate per request. the problem is when I request for first time new token and secret will be generate. it means new token and secret are match. but when I save the token and send it with ajax request (in header or body); this ajax request make old secret expired and will generate a new one. so my token not match with it.

Comment: Check and see if your view engine renders the value of csrf token correctly.

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani it's ok. I have it on my html. when I export a json response and send POST request to it. I give this error. the problem is with POST request!

Comment: Did you set csrf token in your request headers?

Comment: @HamidFzM if you want to request via some clients like post-man you don't have csrf token to set in in header.

Comment: OK, so you should send your csrf token from server to your client. So next time you wsnt to send a request to server then you can use that. The logic is to simple and there is no security problem.

Comment: @HamidFzM I think I found the problem but still I'm try to find a solution. tnx.

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani please check my post update.

Comment: @HamidFzM please check my post update.

Comment: Tell me you want to post a form data or a json data to your express  app? If you want to send a form so you should include a hidden field in your form but if you want to post a json document to your app I think it's a good idea to set a csrf token in request header and check it for you self. But if your problem is none of the above, it's better to run a test on your session manger and check is it working properly?

Comment: @HamidFzM please check Update#2